# Angularjs filter by certain element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-model

I can't find a way to filter my list only by its title.

My list is an array made of objects like this :

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

I also have an input field inside my html file

```
<input type="search" id="search" class="form-control" ng-model="search.title" placeholder="Search by title">
```

This field is being watched in my controller

```
$scope.$watch('search.title', function(val) {
      $log.log($filter('filter')(vm.posts, val));
    });
```

And that's where I want to filter my vm.posts (my list of the objects i mentioned above) only by its title. Instead, it is filtered by its whole object, both `body` and `title` part. I know how to do it in html file by filter:search, but I have no idea how to do this inside a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in two way

```
$scope.$watch('search.title', function(val) {
    $log.log($filter('filter')(vm.posts, $scope.search);
});
```

**OR**

```
$scope.$watch('search.title', function(val) {
    $log.log($filter('filter')(vm.posts, {title: val});
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. The `{title: val}` works like a charm. Haven't thought about that and searched the whole internet for it... Big thanks!

Comment: @NotAJohnDoe np. Glad to help you. Thanks :-)